# Is there a way to code percentage change in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I am trying to get the percentage change of those in the same type and same year, but different groups. Is there a way to do it?

Here's my data df:

```
Year    type      Price      Group
2013     A         100       Old
2013     B         200       Old
2014     A         300       Old
2014     B         500       Old
2013     A         500       New
2013     B         100       New
2014     A         600       New
2014     B         700       New
```

What I'd like to do is to get the percentage change of each type in each year.

For example the percentage change between A in 2013 Old and A in 2013 New.

Is there a way to code it in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `Year` and `Type` you can calculate the percentage change.

The formula I used is `(New - Old)/Old * 100`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Year, type) %>%
  filter(all(c('Old', 'New') %in% Group)) %>%
  summarise(change_perc = (Price[Group == 'New'] - Price[Group == 'Old'])/
                           Price[Group == 'Old'] * 100)

#   Year type  change_perc
#  <int> <chr>       <dbl>
#1  2013 A             400
#2  2013 B             -50
#3  2014 A             100
#4  2014 B              40
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2014L), type = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"
), Price = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 500L, 500L, 100L, 600L, 700L), 
Group = c("Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "New", "New", "New", 
"New")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
Error: Column change_perc must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @vt-0307 Probably, you don't have 'New' or 'Old' value for a particular `Year` and `Type`.

Comment: Is there a way to code such that those that don't have a "new" price or "old" price gets removed?

Comment: It does! Thanks so much!